# Equivalent memcpy different results?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, memcpy

I used memcpy to copy a struct `Vertex` comprised of glm::vec3 objects.
It worked to copy the struct in a class function.
It did not work in the copy constructor that was called when that function returned the class object.

Why?

Class function returning object

```
ShapeData ShapeGenerator::drawTriangle() {
    ShapeData ret;

    Vertex verts[] = {
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

        glm::vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),

        glm::vec3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    };

    ret.numVerts = NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(verts);
    ret.verts = new Vertex[ret.numVerts];
    memcpy(ret.verts, verts, sizeof(verts)); //WORKS

    GLushort indicies[] = {0,1,2};
    ret.numIndicies = NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(indicies);

    ret.indicies = new GLushort[ret.numIndicies];
    memcpy(ret.indicies, indicies, sizeof(indicies));

    return ret;
}
```

Copy Constructor

```
ShapeData(const ShapeData& data) {

    verts = new Vertex[data.numVerts];
    //memcpy(verts, data.verts, sizeof(data.verts)); //DOES NOT WORK
    std::copy( data.verts, data.verts + data.numVerts, verts);


    indicies = new GLushort[data.numIndicies];
    memcpy(indicies, data.indicies, sizeof(data.indicies));

    numVerts = data.numVerts;
    numIndicies = data.numIndicies;

    std::cout << numVerts << std::endl;

}
```

Vertex:

```
#ifndef VERTEX_H
#define VERTEX_H

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

struct Vertex {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 color;
};

#endif
```

Comment: I see that `verts[]` is an array of Vertex objects, but what is the declaration of `indices`?  If, for example, it is a pointer to dynamic memory, `sizeof(indices)` will be the size of a pointer, not of the array pointed to.  You might try `sizeof(indices[0]) * data.numIndices`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
memcpy(verts, data.verts, sizeof(data.verts)); //DOES NOT WORK
```

does not work since `verts` is a pointer, not an array. `sizeof(data.verts)` does not evaluate to the size of the array the pointer points to. It simply evaluates to the size of a pointer on your platform.

You should be able to use:

```
size_t n = sizeof(*data.verts)*data.numVerts;
memcpy(verts, data.verts, n);
```

Comment: Thank you!  And the other one works since it is `Vertex[]` not a `Vertex*`.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Whether or not it works - you should always use `std::copy` and not `memcpy`, because it still works even if the type is not safely memcpyable